# Android v4 Support Library - Call requires API level 11

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library

I've been using (and old version of) v4 Support Library for quite some time with no problems.

With Android 6.0 being released we now need to check for permissions at runtime, and it is recommended to use [ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-check).

So I went ahead and updated the v4 Support Library to its [latest version](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html#rev23-0-1). The first thing I noticed is that it's much heavier: 1.3 MB (the version I was using was only 628 KB).

After updating Eclipse correctly recognizes the call to `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission`.

However, I am now getting this error: `Call requires API level 11 (current min is 9): android.app.Activity#onCreateView`. The error is introduced solely by updating the v4 Support Library (if I rollback the change, the error is gone). I have nothing related to `onCreateView` in my code. The error just points to line 1 of my `MainActivity`, where `package` is declared.

I still need to target APIs 9 and 10, I can't just set the min to 11.

Google states that the v4 Support Library ["is designed to be used with Android 1.6 (API level 4) and higher"](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v4).
Is this a bug with the latest revision of the v4 Support Library?

**EDIT:** I created a new Android Project from scratch and the error still occurs.

Comment: "Is this a bug with the latest revision of the v4 Support Library?" -- it could be a bug with Eclipse. I'd say that's somewhat more likely, given that `support-v4` is maintained, and the ADT Plugin for Eclipse largely isn't.

Comment: @CommonsWare it might. I submitted an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=188677) just in case. The latest release of the v4 Support Library is `Android Support Library, revision 23.0.1 (September 2015)` while there is no September release for ADT, [`ADT 23.0.7 (August 2015)`](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#notes) being the latest